# How to provide values for wtforms.BooleanField and how to add required validator?

Tags: python, flask, wtforms

I am using Python-Flask and I am putting together a small web-app.

I have a boolean field as below:

```
from wtforms import Form, BooleanField, StringField, PasswordField, validators, ValidationError
import json
from Base.Model import db_session, User

class ProductForm(Form):
    Name = ....
    Price = ....
    **HasStone = BooleanField('HasStone', [validators.DataRequired(message="Please enter product FrameShape")])**
```

in flask side I do smth like below:

```
@app.route('/newproduct', methods=['POST'])
def newProduct():
    """creates/edits a proudct."""
    updateSession()
    retJSon = {'errMsg':[], 'data':{}}
    try:
        form = ProductForm( request.form );
        form.TrimOffProductImageURL();
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if form.validate():  <<<<<<< stops here.
```

The form cannot be validated for some reason I don't know. It complains the DataRequired validator cannot be satisfied.

Besides if I take out the validator, the actual boolean value is not copied over to the Product form although I can see the correct values are delivered to the server as properties of the request.form.

Please let know if you could think of a clue.

Thank you,
Mehdi

Comment: Paste error please.

Comment: Why there are semicolons?

Comment: If a `BooleanField` is required, that means the checkbox must be checked. Is that what you want?

Comment: @sudomakeinstall2 semicolons are optional line terminators in python.

Comment: @dirn I thought that means they have to be either true or false and other values are not allowed. Correct me if I am wrong. The thing is that request.form provide values in string format like: 'true' or 'false' and then I use fetch method of the Form. My question is that if the fetch method does the conversion implicitly?

Comment: That isn't how WTForms handles `BooleanField`s. `DataRequired` means there must be data present. This is only the case when a checkbox is checked (that's an HTML thing). The Flask docs even include [an example of validating a `BooleanField`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/patterns/wtforms/). Validation is successful only if the user agrees to the terms.

Comment: A checkbox only appears in the `post` if it is checked.

Comment: Ok correct. provide it as an answer so we can vote it.